# Coupled-mode theory and slowly varying envelope approximation

Tags: approximations, linear-systems, coupled-oscillators

I am facing a situation where I have the following coupled-system equation:

$ \dot{U}(z) = i \; M(z) \cdot U(z) \quad ,$
where U is a N-vector and M is a NxN matrix.

Now, the diagonal elements of M are real-valued while the off-diagonal are imaginary-valued.
Additionally, the diagonal elements are orders of magnitude larger than off-diagonal.
In order to solve this system pertaining, a certain initial condition I was using a standard Runge-Kutta but the z-propagation can be very large and thus the compute time can be very long. The absolute error also builds up with distance.
My research supervisor told me that he would expect the slowly varying envelope approximation (SVEA) to make the computation faster. However, I can't really figure out how is it possible.

Here are the steps I used:

- Let's assume: $U(z) = U_0(z) e^{i k z}$,  here we also assume k (a N-vector) does not depend on z
- Equation becomes: $ \dot{U_0} e^{i k z} + i k U_0 e^{i k z}  = i \; M \cdot U_0 e^{i k z} $
- Equation becomes: $ \dot{U_0} + i k U_0 = i \; M \cdot U_0  $
- Equation becomes: $ \dot{U_0} = i \; ( M - k ) \cdot U_0  $

From here, we see that assuming a **slowly varying envelope** ($U_0$) leads to nowhere.
I hunch that I am missing something obvious here. I also tried deriving a second time, but to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate any input on that matter. Many thanks.

**Starting here, I am using j for the complex notation and bold symbol for matrices.**

Okay, so after scrutinizing the comments of @hyportnex, here is an advancement in my comprehension of the problem:

If I am not mistaken, taking account for $k  = k(z)$, I'd have, for a **two-mode system**:

\begin{align}
    \frac{d U_0(z)}{dz} 
    = 
    j \pmb{M}(z) \; 
    U_0(z)
\\
    \frac{d}{dz} 
    \left( 
        \begin{bmatrix} 
            u_1 e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
            u_2 e^{j k_2 z} 
        \end{bmatrix}  
    \right) = 
    j \pmb{M} 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
        u_2 e^{j k_2 z} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\\
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \dot{u_1} e^{j k_1 z} + j u_1 \left(\dot{k_1} z + k_1 \right) e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
        \dot{u_2} e^{j k_2 z} + j u_2 \left(\dot{k_2} z + k_2 \right) e^{j k_2 z}
    \end{bmatrix}  
    = j \pmb{M}  
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
        u_2 e^{j k_2 z} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Assuming $\dot{k_i}z \ll k_i$:

$
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \dot{u_1} e^{j k_1 z} + j u_1 k_1 e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
    \dot{u_2} e^{j k_2 z} + j u_2 k_2 e^{j k_2 z}
     \end{bmatrix}  
= j \pmb{M}  
\begin{bmatrix} 
    u_1 e^{j k_1 z} \\ 
    u_2 e^{j k_2 z} 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then again, assuming the **slowly varying envelope approximation** (SVEA):

$\dot{u_i} + j u_i k_i \approx j u_i k_i$

Then, I get:

\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 k_1 \\ 
        u_2 k_2
    \end{bmatrix}  
&= \pmb{M} 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
\\
    \Rightarrow 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        k_1 & 0 \\ 
        0 & k_2
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2
    \end{bmatrix} 
&= \pmb{M} 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
\\
    \Rightarrow
    \pmb{k}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2
    \end{bmatrix} 
&= \pmb{M}  
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
\\
    \Rightarrow
    \left( \pmb{M} - \pmb{k} \right)
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        u_1 \\ 
        u_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
&= 0
\end{align}

This means that the state of the amplitude vector $U_0(z)$ do not depend on the state of previous values of $z$ but only on the $\pmb{M}$ coefficients. Now, it does make sense to me. I will run few simulations in order to confirm the intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the *slowly varying* envelope approximation
$$\left\vert \frac{dU_0}{dz}\right\vert \ll k\left\vert U_0(z)\right\vert$$
and therefore
$$\mathfrak j M\cdot U_0(z)e^{\mathfrak j kz} = \frac{dU_0}{dz}e^{\mathfrak j kz}+\mathfrak j ke^{\mathfrak j kz}U_0(z) \approx \mathfrak j ke^{\mathfrak j kz}U_0(z),$$ and thus

$$ M\cdot U_0(z)\approx kU_0(z)$$
in other words $k$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. 
However, I am not entirely sure how to interpret that. While I could solve for the eigen-solution of a particular M and k given, $M(z)$ and $U_0(z)$ are functions of $z$.
As such, I don't really understand how can I propagate the $U_0(z)$ vector in the z dimension.

Comment: Then $k=k(z)$ and for that to make sense $M(z)$ must also be a slowly varying function just as $U_0(z)$. As an analogy think of light propagation in a medium whose dielectric permittivity is a slowly varying function of position relative to wavelengths. If the free space wavenumber is such that $|\tfrac{d\epsilon}{dz}| \ll k_0 \epsilon$ then you can assume that over many wavelengths the envelope of the wave is nearly constant. In RF engineering, in time domain, this is called the *narrowband* approximation relative to the carrier frequency.

Answer (score 0):

starting with

$$ \dot{U}(z) = i \; M(z) \cdot U(z) \tag 1$$

and obtain the eigenvalues $~\lambda_i~$ of $~M(z)~$

where $~\lambda_i=a_i\pm i\,b_i\quad,a_i~,b_i~\in\Re$

with the eigenvectors you can transformed equation (1) to diagonal shape

$$ \dot{U}_D(z) = i \;\underbrace{ T^{-1}\,M(z)\,T}_{\Lambda} \cdot U_D(z) \tag 2$$

where the matrix $~T~$ is the column of eigenvectors and $~\Lambda~$ is diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues.
the differential Equations (2) are uncoupled ans the solution is trivial even if you have high frequencies .

with the solution $~U_D(z)~$ you obtain $~U(z)=T\,U_D(z)~$